# How to set form fields size using bootstrap in React

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to set the fields size using bootstrap in React, basically put all side by side with equal values (row oriented) but I can't get it working, currently is column oriented. I tried all those letters (sm, lg, md, xs etc) but none worked, btw have no idea of the meaning. Can anyone give me a light please?

PS: I don't want to use grid system (rows, cols), make no sense using it in forms. Should exist some easy way to change input fields size. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Just for didactic purpose, i've changed all fields to text.

```
<Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="columnName">

  <Form.Label>Column</Form.Label>
  <Form.Control data-testid="column-filter" type="text" value={ column }/>

  <Form.Label>Condition</Form.Label>
  <Form.Control data-testid="condition-filter" type="text" value={ condition }/>

  <Form.Label>Number</Form.Label>
  <Form.Control data-testid="value-filter" type="text" value={ value }/>

  <Button data-testid="button-filter" type="button" variant="warning">
    Filter
  </Button>

</Form.Group>
```

[image]

Comment: Why ussing bootstrap-4 instead of bootstrap-5?

Comment: @ask4you actually is 5

Comment: Have you had a quick check of the GetBootstrap forms info? They do have some very good form grouping as standard >> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/overview/

Comment: Also, were you asking for an explanation of the breakpoints (xs, sm, md, lg, xl)? All quite logical and nice >> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/